# Embedded associated points of a cokernel sheaf

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,I have a reference request regarding associated points of sheaves. I'll be more specific, assume that we are given the following exact sequence on $\mathbb{P}^d_{\mathbb{C}}$:
$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1)^n \to \mathcal{O}^m \to \mathcal{C} \to 0$. I'm studying the degeneracy locus of $\mathcal{C}$. The case of interest to me is not the generic case, i.e. when the degeneracy locus does not have the expected codimension. I was wondering whether there are some known results regarding embedded points, specifically under what conditions do they appear.

Thank you!

Comment: So you first choose a map $\mathcal O(-1)^n \to \mathcal O^m$, which I guess is a $n \times m$ matrix of sections of $\mathcal O(1)$, and look at the degeneracy locus. Is this just the vanishing set of the determinant ideal, i.e. the intersection of `$\left(\begin{array}{c} m \\ n \end{array}\right)$` sections of $\mathcal O(m)$? You are looking for embedded points of this determinant ideal?

Comment: Precisely. That is what I am looking for. 